# What is a quicker way of gathering color values?

Tags: processing

I want to store colour 10 colour values. I'm positive there is a more elegant way of doing this. What is it?

```
color a = get(25, 25);
color b = get(50, 50);
color c = get(75, 75);
color d = get(100, 100);
color e = get(125, 125);
color f = get(150, 150);
color g = get(175, 175);
color h = get(200, 200);
color i = get(225, 225);
color j = get(250, 250);

HColorPool colors = new HColorPool(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j);
```

Comment: Use a loop? How are you using those variables?

Comment: I'm using them to color different fills
HColorPool colors = new HColorPool(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is the obvious choice for this kind of thing. If your `get()` calls are always as predictable as your example, then you could also use a loop to automate it; e.g.:

```java
color[] colors = new color[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    colors[i] = get(25*(i+1), 25*(i+1));
}
```

When you want to use the individual colors, you can access them as `color[0]`, `color[1]`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

HColorPool has an [`.add` function](http://www.hypeframework.org/examples/HColorPool/example_002/index.html) which allows you to add colors as you go.

```java
HColorPool colors = new HColorPool();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  colors.add( get( 25*(i+1), 25*(i+1) ) );
}
```

If your color locations aren't as predictable as in your example, maybe something like this is more useful:

```java
HColorPool colors = new HColorPool(
  get(25, 25),
  get(50, 50),
  get(75, 75),
  get(100, 100),
  get(125, 125),
  get(150, 150),
  get(175, 175),
  get(200, 200),
  get(225, 225),
  get(250, 250)
);
```